# WAMP - PHP loads too many Extensions

Tags: wamp, php, wampserver

i am using WAMP 2.1 with
Apache Version :   2.2.17
PHP Version :    5.3.3
MySQL Version :  5.5.8

By default WAMP loads these extensions
      Core, bcmath, calendar, com_dotnet, ctype, date, ereg, filter, tp, hash, iconv, json, mcrypt, session, odbc, pcre, Reflection, standard, SPL, mysqlnd, tokenizer, zip, zlib, libxml, dom, PDO, Phar, SimpleXML, wddx, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, apache2handler, gd, mbstring, mysql, mysqli, mhash

i really dont need all these !
so i opened **PHP.INI** and put a ; before those  lines which i dont want, so now it looks like
**;extension=php_zip.dll** but WAMP still shows ZIP extensions as loaded !
what is wrong ?
i restarted WAMP but with no effect !

Answer (score 0):

To be able to change extension loading settings, you MUST run WampServer as administrator. (Right Click WampServer shortcut -> Run As Administrator). This should work now.

<del>Click the Wamp icon in the system tray, then click PHP > PHP Extensions and try checking/unchecking the items there. This should work.</del> <-- Checking/unchecking these items is the same as editing php.ini

Comment: i'm running as admin still no luck :(